# About sign up with facebook into android app

Tags: android

I follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) tutorial and  I created sign up with facebook into android app. When I test it give this messege "App not setup: this app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. switch to registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions" . Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add email id in fb console

Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email. (Give any email)

then in 'Status and Review' Tab

by default it is No,change it to yes

Comment: I add the email address but still it give same message @Lakhan

Comment: did you change in status and review tab?

Comment: and you need to add your details and send it to fb for verification

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add your Key Hash to the app on Facebook.

To generate it:

On OS X, run:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   &#126;/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
>   base64

On Windows, run:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
>   base64

This generates a 28 character string. Use this in the Settings section of your app on Facebook.